# TPL/PHP: Checkbox checked on page load

Tags: php, smarty, testlink

I need the page to bring this option checked by default in loading the page, but even putting the same check comes in white.

Note that the other field, has a similar structure and comes checked when loading the page.

```
<tr>
    <td></td><td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="optInventory" 
        {if $gui->projectOptions->inventoryEnabled} checked="checked"  {/if} />
        {$labels.testproject_enable_inventory}
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is checked by default when loading the page:

```
 <tr>
    <td></td><td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_public" {if $gui->is_public eq 1} checked="checked"  {/if} />
        {$labels.public}
      </td>
  </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: The Task Parallel  Library has nothing to do with PHP. That's pretty obvious by the name itself and the description. If you have a question about smarty, use the proper tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output the option value to see if it is really what you expect. Also, I think that Smarty (at least some older versions) don't allow multiple use of `->` in an expression. Try to first assign the options to a template variable and then use that in your checkbox:

```
{assign var=opts value=$gui->projectOptions}
<input type="checkbox" {if $opts->inventoryEnabled}checked="checked"{/if} />
```